# remove everything after a specific word (string) in AS3

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3

I've got this string and I want to divide it into multiple strings by removing everything after a specific word and when another specific word starts.

Example text :

*"Today forecast is this one. This morning : the sun will be generous everywhere. Wind will be strong but nothing dangerous. Wind speed will be 30 knt. This afternoon : clouds will hide the sun. It may rain during the afternoon but not too much. This night : rain will fall. It will be a full moon. Tomorrow morning : blblablb"*

I'd like to create multiple strings of each "section". A morning string section, an afternoon string section, a night string section..etc

If we take my morning string for example : how can I delete everything before "This morning" and everything from "this afternoon" (in order to only have, in my morning string : "This morning : the sun will be generous everywhere.")

So, if I'm correct, I've managed to select from "This morning" by doing that :

```
var str: String = "Today forecast is this one. This morning : the sun will be generous everywhere. This afternoon : clouds will hide the sun. This night : rain will fall. Tomorrow morning : blblablblabla";  

var search_morning_starts: Number = str.indexOf("This");  
var morning_str:String = str.substring(search_morning_starts,str.length);  
trace(morning_str);
```

But how can I add to delete everything from "this afternoon" ?

(can't say "delete everything after "everywhere" because the word "everywhere" won't be written every time. It depends on the weather of the morning. So I need to delete everything when "this afternoon"appears)

**EDIT**

Their can be multiple sentences in one forecast "day"

**EDIT 2**

I've never used Regex. If someone could give me an example how to select a part in my text, I will be grateful.

Comment: Try regex, perhaps start with https://regex101.com/r/qJiNJa/1

Comment: I cannot guarantee that dot symbol will not appear inside the sentences, but I think you should at least start with **str.split(".");**

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I forgot to precise something (I'll edit my post).
There are more than one sentences per forecast (I just put 1 sentence as an example in my text) so I can't split it with "."
I can have multiple sentences in one forecast like that 
_Today forecast is this one. This morning : the sun will be generous everywhere. Wind will be strong but nothing dangerous. Wind speed will be 30 knt. This afternoon : clouds will hide the sun. It may rain during the afternoon but not too much. This night : rain will fall. It will be a full moon. Tomorrow morning : blblablb_

Comment: @Organis : regex is working with as3 ? I don't know regex but in your link when I hit "code generator", there's no AS3 (only : javascript, php, pyhton, c#, java,ruby,rust,golang,perl)

Comment: @Steph **RegExp** is a built-in AS3 class, yes: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html

Comment: @Organis Thanks ! Would you be kind enough to show me an example with the sentence " _This morning : the sun will be generous everywhere. Wind will be strong but nothing dangerous._" ? I'm a fast learner with example...

Comment: Will the forecast have always "This morning :", "This afternoon :" etc? If that's 100% happening, then you can simply use `.split()` with those phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the forecast will always have the same structure ("This morning : ... This afternoon : ... This night : ... Tomorrow morning : ..."), you can safely use those phrases to double split sections from it.

I'm not saying this is the best or most efficient way to do it, but it should work if your forecasts has that consistency.

```
var str:String = "Today forecast is this one. This morning : the sun will be generous everywhere. Wind will be strong but nothing dangerous. Wind speed will be 30 knt. This afternoon : clouds will hide the sun. It may rain during the afternoon but not too much. This night : rain will fall. It will be a full moon. Tomorrow morning : blblablb";

var separators:Array = new Array("This morning :","This afternoon :","This night :","Tomorrow morning :");

function separate(forecast:String):Object{
    var obj:Object = new Object();
    obj.pre = forecast.split(separators[0])[0];
    obj.morning = forecast.split(separators[0])[1].split(separators[1])[0];
    obj.afternoon = forecast.split(separators[1])[1].split(separators[2])[0];
    obj.night = forecast.split(separators[2])[1].split(separators[3])[0];
    obj.tomorrow = forecast.split(separators[3])[1];
    return obj;
}
var forecastObj:Object = separate(str);

trace(forecastObj.pre);
trace("This morning :"+forecastObj.morning);
trace("This afternoon :"+forecastObj.afternoon);
trace("This night :"+forecastObj.night);
trace("Tomorrow morning :"+forecastObj.tomorrow);
```